# I am getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1" when using JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I'm having trouble accessing the list `param = ['foo','bar']` on `myView.js`.

the JS code is treating `param` as if it were a string, but when I try `JSON.parse(param)` I get the error shown below.

What am I missing here?

### myView.html:

```
    <script>
    window.obj = {};
    obj.param = "{{ param | safe }}";
    </script>
```

### views.py:

```
    def myView(req):
        context = {'param':['foo','bar']}
        return render(req, 'myView.html', context)
```

### myView.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      console.log(window.obj.param); //prints ['foo','bar']
      console.log(window.obj.param[0]); //prints [
      console.log(JSON.parse(window.obj.param)); // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

      //what I need to happen
      console.log(param[0]); // prints 'foo'
});
```

Comment: json format allows only double quotes (`token ' in JSON at position 1`)

Comment: Thanks!  If you post an answer Ill accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json format allows only double quotes (`token ' in JSON at position 1`), sting with single quotes is not a valid json format, so if you try to parse it, you will get an error, as demonstrated here

```js
function safeParse(param){
    try {
        console.log(JSON.parse(param))
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("there was an issue with parsing your string")
    }
}
safeParse("['foo','bar']");
safeParse('["foo","bar"]');
```